# How do I use Google Calendar API credentials?

Tags: google-calendar-api, credentials, react-big-calendar

I'm developing my own website with React JS and Django. The idea is a calendar website for making events. I did a Google Calendar integration following the article
[Google Calendar API with Python](https://dev.to/nelsoncode/google-calendar-api-con-python-1ib1)

In order to use a Google Calendar, I got my OAuth Client Id and put them in `credentials.json` file inside my root folder. When I press a button "Integrate Google Calendar" in my own website, the request is sent to the server where I check if there is the file `credentials.json` and make a new file for credentials named `token.txt` in the same folder. And right after that I retrieve events from the calendar passing the credentials received from the `token.txt`.

```
service = build("calendar", "v3", credentials=creds)
```

The problem is, when I have a lot of users and requests, the file `token.txt` is overwritten, so I can get someone else's events. What is the best idea for storing credentials for every single user? Should I store them in binary in a database?

Answer (score 3):

### Issue number 1.

You say you are creating a web app. Yet the example you are following is for an installed app hence the

```
InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file
```

### Issue number 2.

The sample you are following as it is for an installed app is designed for single user.  The users consent is stored with in the  token pickle.

```
pickle.dump(creds, open("token.txt", "wb"))
```

### Solution.

Find an example for using with webappclient.  Try looking around in [client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/docs/oauth.md) There should be something there. or this [web-server#python_1](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#python_1)

```
# OAuth 2 client setup
client = WebApplicationClient(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID)
```